# How to select scripts inside a suite(.xml) to run in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin in Jenkins that allows the user to select scripts/java classes inside a Suite(.xml) to be executed in Jenkins?

We have a Selenium Suite and we created a job in jenkins for that. We have 10 TCs inside the suite. I would like to run only TC 5-8. Is there a plugin that will create a checkbox for each TC then we can tick the checkbox that we like to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my sample xml file

```
<test name="TestCase1">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase1"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase2">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase2"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase3">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase3"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase4">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase4"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase15">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase5"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase6">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase6"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase7">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase7"/>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="TestCase8">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase8"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="TestCase9">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase9"/>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="TestCase10">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.sanity.ui.TestCase10"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```